# Relate outputs of parent function to input of nested function

Tags: matlab, function, optimization, nested

I am going to try and explain myself simply in the hopes of getting a simple answer.

Let's say I have a function 'calculate' that takes the inputs `[t,k,r,x]` and outputs `[A,B,C,D]` as follows:

```
function [A,B,C,D] = calculate(t,k,r,x)
```

Now lets say I have another function that takes these outputs as the inputs, and spits out more, different outputs, eg.

```
function [M,N] = again(A,B,C,D)
```

How do I link `[M,N]` to say `k` and `t`? The overall aim is to minimise both `M` and `N` by optimising `k` and `t`, and I can guess that it has something to do with nested functions and passing parameters but I'm not sure how to start, and the start is all I want. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [the Matlab optimization toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/getting-started-with-optimization-toolbox.html). It provides functions for a multitude of optimization problems. Although I believe these functions only take one function as a parameter. Therefore for your case it would probably be best, if you do it like this if you can:

1. Write function `calculate.m` with parameters (t,k,r,x) and save it.
2. Write function `again.m` with parameters(t,k,r,x) and save it.
3. Function `again` calls function `calculate` with parameters (t,k,r,x) and then continues to determine (M,N) from the output of `calculate`.
4. in the Matlab toolbox optimization function, e.g.: fmincon(fun,x0,A,b), you then have to use again.m as the function you want to optimize (fun).

Hope that's good enough for a start.

Comment: Hi, this was excellent. I was worrying about the order of nesting functions when I completely overlooked (I don't know why) just writing them separately and have one call another. So now, I come to something I know I can't pass on my own. I know that the toolbox (no matter what optimisation tool you want to use) only take one variable as an input. In the case of the original problem, how do I formulate the objective function, such that the outputs are still ``[M,N]`` but that the optimiser (GA in this case) optimises the variables I would like. I imagine some form of mapping needs to occur?

Comment: First you should figure out which kind of problem you have: linear, nonlinear, do you have any constraints, .... As mentioned, the objective  function, which is the function you want to optimize, should be the again.m

Comment: My problem is though, how do I convert the specific named variables (t,k) that I want to optimise into one variable (z, lets say) for the input of the objective function?